# Vaadin : Upload button listener

Tags: button, upload, listener, vaadin

How can I get the upload button listener of component upload? This is because I want to validate other fields upon clicking the upload button. I've tried adding...

```
upload.addListener(new Upload.StartedListener() {});
```

It only works if there is already a chosen file but if the file is blank, it didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to hide the submit button of Upload with CSS and create a button that calls:

```
upload.submitUpload();
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to hide the 'Upload' Button with CSS.

Another simple way to hide:

```
Upload upload = new Upload("Caption", receiver);

upload.setButtonCaption(null);//will hide the Upload Button
```

Comment: The docs of `Upload.submitUpload()` also advise to do it like this. But why doesn't the Upload component itself doesn't provide a way to handle the click of the built-in button? If the user doesn't select any file and simply clicks the 'Upload' button and the `receiveUpload()` method of the Receiver implementation returns null when an exception during FiloOutputStream creation is caught, a `NoOutputStreamException` is thrown... Is there a way to handle this preventing the exception from firing while still using the default, built-in 'Upload' button and without `upload.setButtonCaption(null);`?